# how to sign a certificate by another one in java using bouncy castle?

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle, signature

I am trying to sign an end entity certificate with a CA certificate using bouncy castle in java .
I tried tuto but I couldn t find the right solution.
how can I achieve it?

Comment: Complicated.. something along the lines of http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/CreatingaCertificatefromaCertificationRequest.htm and http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sign an end entity certeficate by a ca cert using a given private key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928762/how-to-sign-an-end-entity-certeficate-by-a-ca-cert-using-a-given-private-key)